# What is the most optimize way to use annotate with Count function with many filter in django query

Tags: python, sql, django, postgresql, django-rest-framework

For example in school, there is many data to store example "Class", "Student", "Book", etc. Also, the model used softdelete(softdelete refers to action when delete just change the `is_deleted` to `True` in the model). In each model, there are `create_time`, `update_time`, `is_delete`, etc. In my code now I use the method below, it spent at least 30s to run sql.

So what is the most optimised way to query `Count` with the filter that contains many conditions?  Also sometimes we need to count the same model but using the different filter

Here is an example of code in Django (Check count data for each school).

```py
# In this code, each model already implements softdelete manager query.
School.objects.annotate(
    number_of_class=Count(
        "class", filter=Q(class__is_deleted=False, class__create_time__lte=datetime, ...more filter), distinct=True
    ),
    number_of_student=Count(
        "student", filter=Q(student__is_deleted=False, student__create_time__lte=datetime, ...more filter), distinct=True
    ),
    number_of_public_book=Count(
        "book", filter=Q(book__is_deleted=False, book__create_time__lte=datetime, book__create_time__gte=datetime, book__type=1, ...more filter), distinct=True
    ),
    number_of_private_book=Count(
        "book", filter=Q(book__is_deleted=False, book__create_time__lte=datetime, book__create_time__gte=datetime, book__type__in=[2,3], ...more filter), distinct=True
    )
    more_count...
)
```

**Please help give all code queries that you know and what you think can be optimised for counting with many counts and filters.**

Comment: A [mcve] is a great start when asking for SQL assistance.

Answer (score 0):

Since you each time filter out removed books, you can already omit these from all counts with:

```
School.objects.filter(
    book__is_deleted=False,
    book__create_time__lte=datetime,
    book__create_time__gte=datetime,
).annotate(
    number_of_public_book=Count('book', filter=Q(book__type=1)),
    number_of_private_book=Count('book', filter=Q(book__type__in=[2, 3])),
)
```

Furthermore *don't* make aggregates over different `JOIN`s in the same query: this "blows up" records, since now we have a row per book and per class for each school, and this means you have to work with a [**`distinct=True`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.Count.distinct) slowing down the process, make queries *per* table you join over. So in this case, one for the books, one for the classes, etc. In such queries you can batch different counts for books, like is done in the code sample above.

Finally add a [**`db_index=True`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/fields/#db-index) on `is_deleted` and `create_time` to boost performance.

Comment: but in this code it will not show the school if that school has no book.

Comment: @ChreaChanchhunneng: no that is correct, but you make a query for books, a query for classes, etc. The merge then is done on the Django level. The main factor for optimization is however to do *one* JOIN per query, this will remove the `distinct=True` filters, and also reduce the amount of rows that are generated by these `JOIN`s.

Comment: The reason the query is thus not efficient is because if you combine the `classes` and `books`, etc. It will make *multiple* `LEFT OUTER JOIN`s, as a result if a school has 12 books and 10 classes, now there are no 12 or 10 or 22 rows for that `school`, but 120. If we add an extra item for join `teachers`, and there are five teachers, we will even get 600 rows for that school, so we get exponential growth.